# Error on sending configuration file to fiware cepheus cep GE

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I've encountered a problem while using cepheus cep Fiware component . I prepared the config.json file setting the structure of incoming and outcome data as well as the Esper SQL statements which should process the incoming data and generate the output data with the preset structure in the configuration. i want to send updates to the Cepheus with Sensor motion data telling whether somebody entered the room (sending 1) or somebody left the room (sends -1) and then sum the motion incoming value with the previous number of people in the room to see if there're people remaining in the room . and this the json configuration file that i've made till now  .

```
{
        "host":"http://localhost:8080",
"in":[
    {
      "id":"Lab.*",
      "type":"Lab",
      "isPattern": true,
      "attributes":[
        { "name":"motion", "type":"integer","metadata": [
            { "name":"unit", "type":"string" }
          ] }
    ,

{ "name":"controller", "type":"string"}],

      "providers":[
        "http://localhost:8081"
      ]
    }
  ],

"out":[
    {
      "id":"ControllerX",
      "type":"Controller",
      "attributes":[

    {  "name":"number", "type":"integer"

       }

]
,

      "brokers":[
        {
          "url":"http://147.27.60.58:1026"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
"statements":[ "INSERT INTO Controller  SELECT controller as id , motion prev(count(*)+number) as number From Lab.win:keepall()  INNER JOIN Controller.win:keepall() ON controller = id    

" 

    ]
```

as the file shows , the statement generates output event after getting the previous number of people from the last output event and sum it with the motion input (1 or -1) to get the people number of the new output event but when i send the config.json file i get this error :

```
{"code":"400","reasonPhrase":"Failed to apply new configuration","details":"Error starting statement: Failed to validate select-clause expression 'motion+number': Implicit conversion from datatype 'Object' to numeric is not allowed [insert into Controller select controller as id, motion+number as number from Lab.win:keepall() inner outer join Controller.std:lastevent() on controller = id]"}
```

does this error mean that the summed values are recognized as objects not integers ?  and if so ,how could it be solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the attribute types supported by Cepheus CEP, in this case `int` ?

These are the supported attributes types: `string`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, `date` and `geo:point`.

Comment: Thanks so much .. i solved the problem testing with both types "int" and "double" successfully